# Multiple figures layout

Tags: tables, multirow

I have 5 figures: A, b, c, d, e.  I have a question in laying out multi-figures like below:

```
---------
 A | b c
 A | d e           {  A  } is a single long figure using multirow
---------             A
```

A is a long figure, and b, c, d and e are small square figures. I tried to use multirow to create one. But it works bad. The figures generated by my code is like this:

```
 --------
    | b c 
 A  | d e
 A
 --------
```

My code is here:

```
    \begin{table*}[t]
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
\multirow{2}{*}{  
      \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{figs/cluster/gMaps.eps}
    } &  
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{figs/cluster/2.eps}
  &   
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{figs/cluster/5.eps}
  \\   &  
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{figs/cluster/10.eps}
  &  
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{figs/cluster/20.eps}
  \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

How can I create the layout?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest do create a new column type. This works with the `\newcolumntype` Maybe take a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/centering-mutirow-text-in-a-table-whose-cells-contain-several-lines-of-text).
In your situation this might look like this:

```
\newcolumntype{VC}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

% write some stuf

\begin{tabular}{VC{0.2\textwidth}VC{0.2\textwidth}VC{0.2\textwidth}}
%now you should be able to do your multirow stuff
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got a solution. I use multrow{3}. The result generated is good for me. Below is the code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\subfigure[Original Check-in Distribution]{\includegraphics[height=25em]{figs/cluster/gMaps.eps}}} & & 
\\
    & \subfigure[\( k^{+} = 2 \)  ]{\includegraphics[width=0.21\textwidth]{figs/cluster/EII_2.eps}} &   
    \subfigure[\( k^{+} = 5\) ]{\includegraphics[width=0.21\textwidth]{figs/cluster/EII_5.eps}} \\
    & \subfigure[\( k^{+} = 10 \) ]{\includegraphics[width=0.21\textwidth]{figs/cluster/EII_10.eps}} &  
    \subfigure[\( k^{+} = 20 \) ]{\includegraphics[width=0.21\textwidth]{figs/cluster/EII_20.eps}} \\
    \end{tabular}

 \caption{Clustering Result}
    \label{fig:cluster}
  \end{center}

\end{figure*}
```

Hope this could help other latex users.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)