# how to put words in several lines in one cell?

Tags: tables

The table is too wide, and I want to make it narrower by wrapping the `Second` under the `First`, how should I achieve this?

The latex code looks like this currently:

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]


 \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Violations} & \textbf{First Second} & \textbf{First Second} & \textbf{First Second} & \textbf{First Second} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1   & 0   & 91  & 101 & 507 & 1973.54 \bigstrut[t]\\
    2   & 0   & 102 & 92  & 472 & 1874.65 \\
    3   & 0   & 104 & 92  & 459 & 1856.21 \\
    4   & 0   & 108 & 100 & 407 & 1790.56 \\
    5   & 0   & 112 & 77  & 511 & 1723.66 \\
    $\ldots$   & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
```

[image]

Comment: @Werner the "violations" needed to be center at the row, is it possible?

Comment: Also see [Centering mutirow text in a table whose cells contain several lines of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30551/5764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the minimalistic [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) that could adjust the alignment of a specific cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Violations} & 
      \bfseries\makecell[c]{First \\ Second} & 
      \bfseries\makecell[c]{First \\ Second} & 
      \bfseries\makecell[c]{First \\ Second} & 
      \bfseries\makecell[c]{First \\ Second} \\
    \hline
    5   & 0   & 112 & 77  & 511 & 1723.66 \\
    $\ldots$   & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could make the code even shorter using the `\thead`command and declaring `\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way would be to just use two lines. To place the single line heading in the center of the row you can use `\multirow` from [the `multirow` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
 \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\#}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Violations}} & \textbf{First} & \textbf{First} & \textbf{First } & \textbf{First } \\
                &  & \textbf{Second} & \textbf{Second} & \textbf{Second} & \textbf{Second} \\
    \hline
    5   & 0   & 112 & 77  & 511 & 1723.66 \\
    $\ldots$   & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$  & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$   & $\ldots$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I need the violations to be placed at the centre of the row, is  it possible?

Comment: @sweetyBaby: Have updated solution to do that.