# Different vertical alignment with multirow

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, multirow

I have longtable with multirow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell,array}

\begin{document}

{
\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}{ \centering \textbf{Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text}} & Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
 & Long long   long long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
 & Long long  long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
 & Long long  long long  long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{1-3}
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need use columns with specific width **\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep** Here I use a simple example, but in general, the column can be larger and the text is not fixed length.

I want the last column has vertical alignment. I have problem in first column.

I want to get one of the images:
[image]
[image]

How can I fix it?

**Update.** I need use mulrirow and longtable. The figure is the full version of the table in which the problem occurred.
[image]

Comment: longtable `[H]` ???

Comment: in your p column width you have allowed for \tabcolsep but not for arrayrulewidth

Comment: You can compare your problem with my thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183235/vertically-aligned-table-in-plaintex-latex-context-etc.

Comment: @wipet Similar problem, but there are not presented solutions for Latex

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without using `multirow`. In a lot of cases you can use a nested tabular. `ltablex` is a combination of `longtable` and `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}   
\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|@{}m{0.66\linewidth}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline
\bfseries Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text  
  &
   \begin{tabular}{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}}  
      Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
     & 11111  \\\hline
      Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
     & 11111  \\\hline 
      Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
     & 11111
   \end{tabular}  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a solution what I'am waiting for in my thread, isn't it? My thread is called "Vertically aligned table in plainTeX, LaTeX, Context, etc". LaTeX solution is missing here. Would you post your ideas to this thread too?

Comment: This method works in the simple case. But I have a lot in the general table mulrirows.

Comment: I never use `multirow`. I have a lot of tables and it is _always_  possible to use nested tabulars instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second optional argument (called `fixup`) of `\multirow`.

```
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}[2.5em]{\centering...
```

`2.5em` is an empirical value which you should adjust manually.

[image]

A negative value will lower the entry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell,array}

\begin{document}

{
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|m{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline
\multirow{4}{\linewidth}[-5.8em]{\centering \textbf{Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text}} & Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \\[-1.85em] \cline{2-3}     %% adjust -5.8em and 1.85em suitably
 & Long long   long long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
 & Long long  long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
 & Long long  long long  long long long long long long long long long long long text & 1111 \tabularnewline \cline{1-3}
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution, but not automatic(